# Azure Automation - Runbook parameters not found?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

After adding a runbook with parameters, I'm unable to start it, either in the Test Pane or as a Job after publishing.

- Runbooks that existed prior to this do populate parameters.
- Unable to start a Test Job in ISE (aka, it's not simply a Portal/browser problem).
- GET from the ARM API returns a runbook with an empty Parameters property.

[edit] I should probably add it doesn't matter if I have `[CmdletBinding()]` specified or not. [/edit]

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runbook (script) in your screenshot contains a function definition (which takes parameters), but does not ever call the function. Your runbook does not take parameters, the function does. That is why the test pane is showing no parameters.

Try this:

```
param([string]$Bar)

function test-set {
  param([string]$Bar)
  "$Bar"
}

test-set -Bar $Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

My memory of this 'support' was incorrect. As Joe points out, Workflow runbooks require the function declaration, but old-school scripts do not.

Commenting the `function func-name { }` bits allows the runbook parameters to be found again..

Comment: "Previously, these scripts could include the function func-name { } syntax." - don't think that is true. You may be thinking of "workflow workflow-name {}" syntax, which is how its done for PowerShell Workflow runbooks. But this is a PowerShell script runbook.

Comment: I unearthed the old versions of scripts the recollection was from and found they did make the func call at the end, splatting PSBoundParameters. Must've been left-over from trying to test them all locally in ISE to fish out errors that wouldn't occur or didn't surface the same once published.